# Need to return all the values of a key from the api response using python

Tags: python, json, api, response

I am trying to list the values of country from the api response. While I tired it is throwing an error as TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries")
json_response = response.json()
# dictionary = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys = True, indent = 4)

country_name = json_response['data']['country']
```

I have taken the api endpoint from the browser where i need to list out the country values and check whether the data i extracted as text matches the country values present in the api endpoint.

Can you please let me know where I am using doing the mistake, as i was stuck on this for past wo days.

When I give it as

```
country_name = json_response['data'][0]['country']
```

the first country name is getting printed but i need all the values of country.

Comment: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` what it's saying is that a list cannot be indexed with strings, or in normal terms, you can get a value with a string, instead, you need a number to index it

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the data list items and pick the value with key `country` and append to the list

```py
countries = []
for country in json_response['data']:
    countries.append(country['country'])
print(countries)
```

---

Another method using list comprehension:

```py
countries = [json_response['data'][i]['country'] for i in range(len(json_response['data']))]
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works. One more thing in that api endpoint cities are there which is a list inside a json object how can i search the word which i extracted in another list with that cities list and print the matching cities

Comment: This is another question that you should open a new thread. I have precisely answered your question already

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over everything in the list `json_response['data']` and pull out `country`:

```
countries = [json_response['data'][i]['country'] for i in len(json_response['data'])]
```

Comment: Its throwing an error as "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable", can you please help me with it..

Answer (score 0):

Your response data is a nested list. You need to loop through it to retrieve all values:

```py
countries = [x['country'] for x in json_response['data']]
# or
countries = list(map(lambda x: x['country'], json_response['data']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `country_name = json_response['data']['country']` breaks is that `json_response['data']` gives you a `list` which can only be indexed by `int` or numbers hence the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

here is a much simpler version of what they're trying to do

```
countries = []
for country in json_response["data"]:
    countries.append(country["country"])

print(countries)
```